# VB .Net can't reference a byte* pointer in a method from an unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pointers

I have an unmanaged DLL in C# that has a method whose signature has a byte*.  Something like this:

```
    [DllExport("ImportImage", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static unsafe string ImportImage(..., byte* image, int fileLength, ...) {
```

I am able to call it from my test harness in C# using:

```
    [DllImport("AmerihealthCmPassthrough.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern unsafe String ImportImage( ..., byte* image, int fileLength, ...);

        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Temp/1-1.png");
        string retVal = "";
        fixed (byte* p = fileBytes) {
            retVal = SCSImportImage(..., p, fileBytes.Length, ...);
        } // fixed
```

However, I can't find any way to create a corresponding call from VB.Net.  Is there a way to call what I have defined?  If not, how do I define something that can be called from VB.Net?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: VB.NET doesn't support pointers, so there isn't an _exact_ translation of the C# code. However an unmanaged byte pointer can easily be mapped to an array, so a simple `Byte()` should do the trick (infact I think you should have done the same C#, the use of pointers seems superfluous).

Comment: @Visual Vincent - I realized that using a byte* was probably overkill for an array and changed it to an IntPtr on the C# side.  I then used "Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)image, imageBytes, 0, fileLength);" to copy the bytes in a local array definition.  I am still having issues on the VB.Net side.  I have tried "pinning" the memory in VB.net and am still getting a memory access violation error.

Comment: But normally you shouldn't need all of that. As I said in my previous comment byte pointers (C/C++ `unsigned char*`) are usually mapped to regular byte arrays (`Byte()` in VB.NET and `byte[]` in C#). This is due to the fact that all reference types (classes) are passed by their reference pointer, meaning when you pass the array to the unmanaged function you are actually giving it the byte pointer that it is looking for.

Comment: You should be able to just declare your P/Invoke in the following manner: `static extern unsafe string ImportImage(..., byte[] image, int fileLength, ...);` (or in VB.NET: `Shared Function ImportImage(..., ByVal image As Byte(), ByVal fileLength As Integer, ...) As String`).

Comment: (also using `byte*` in C# is easier than using the `Marshal` class, so if a regular byte array fails I would stick to the former. You could try to convert the `Marshal` code to VB.NET first, though, if using a byte array still doesn't work)